# How do I format title text using Pelican?

Tags: python, markdown, pelican

I'm using Pelican with Markdown. I create blog posts as `foo.md` files, which look like this:

```
Title: Light, by Kelly Link
Date: 2015-09-07 21:18

Blah blah ...
```

I would like a word in the title to be italicized, but I can't use markdown in the `Title:` field (if I write `*Light*, by Kelly Link` it's interpreted literally. Do I have to change the theme in order to do this?

Comment: Since the `*` is not being processed by markdown, you could try `Title: <i>Light</i>, by Kelly Link`

Comment: @JohnLaRooy, using raw HTML probably won't work as it will be escaped by the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the relevant section of code in Pelican is, I believe, the following from `readers.py` (starting c. line 183):

```
def _parse_metadata(self, meta):                                               
    """Return the dict containing document metadata"""                         
    formatted_fields = self.settings['FORMATTED_FIELDS']                       

    output = {}                                                                
    for name, value in meta.items():                                           
        name = name.lower()                                                    
        if name in formatted_fields:                                           
            # handle summary metadata as markdown                              
            # summary metadata is special case and join all list values        
            summary_values = "\n".join(value)                                  
            # reset the markdown instance to clear any state                   
            self._md.reset()                                                   
            summary = self._md.convert(summary_values)                         
            output[name] = self.process_metadata(name, summary)
```

In short, Pelican is looking to see if it is supposed to parse Markdown fields before writing them (`title` is part of the `meta` `dict`). Based on that, it looks like all you need to do is make sure that you have `title` in your `FORMATTED_FIELDS` setting.

Comment: Thanks, quite helpful! I did this, but now for some reason the `<p></p>` that Pelican wraps the formatted text in has an enormous margin.

Comment: @EliRose What is the markup it returns? You may need to modify the CSS now.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, quite helpful! I did this, but now for some reason the `<p></p>` that Pelican wraps the formatted text in has an enormous margin. – Eli Rose Sep 8 '15 at 2:26

You can often avoid the `<p></p>` wrapping by amending the `title` variable in your theme's html pages to `title|striptags`. This solves several other problems (e.g. all-caps sections in titles) that Typogrify sometimes creates.

For example:

```
{% for p in PAGES %}
    <li{% if p == page %} class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title|striptags }}</a></li>
```